# Executing Class with multiple parameters in Python

Tags: python, class

New to classes...

I have this class specified below, and I am trying to call it.  Basically what the function inside does is takes a list, removes certain numbers from the list and returns the length of the list.  So if I have:

```
nums = [5,6,6,7,8], val = 6
```

It should return a length of 3 (3 numbers remaining in list)

Here is my code, but when I execute it I get 'Solution' object is not callable:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        lens = len(nums)
        if lens == 0:
            return 0
        x = 0
        for i in range(lens):
            if nums[i] != val:
                nums[x] = nums[i]
            x += 1
        return x


a_solution = Solution()
a_solution([5,6,6,7,8], 6)
```

Comment: You don't execute classes. You instantiate classes, and execute methods of the class instances.

Comment: Also, there's an indentation issue in your program. The line `x += 1` should be inside the `if` statement.

Comment: `a_solution` cannot be called as a `method`, try to use @Norrius solution.

Comment: If you’re not actually using the class for anything (notice that your method never accesses `self`, so it’s basically just irrelevant noise), you probably shouldn’t have a class in the first place. If you’re just looking to group some related functions together, what you probably want is a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would rewrite your class to perform what you want

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        lens = len(nums)
        if lens == 0:
            return 0
        x = 0
        for i in range(lens):
            if nums[i] != val:
                nums[x] = nums[i]
                x += 1
        return x

# This line creates an instance of the Solution class
a_solution = Solution()
# This line calls the method removeElement
a_solution.removeElement([5,6,6,7,8], 6)
```

Here's another version that takes advantage of using a class by setting some instance variable called to_add

```
class CustomSolution:

    # This method (function) gets run whenever you create an instance
    # of this class
    def __init__(self, to_add):
        # The self keyword means that each instance of the class
        # (rather than the class itself) can have it's own
        # 'to_add' variable
        self.to_add = to_add

    def removeElement(self, nums, val):
        lens = len(nums)
        if lens == 0:
            return 0
        x = 0
        for i in range(lens):
            if nums[i] != val:
                nums[x] = nums[i]
                x += 1
        return x + self.to_add


# Now we create an instance where the amount to add is 20
a_20_solution = Solution(to_add=20)
# This line calls the method removeElement but the result is now different!
a_20_solution.removeElement(nums=[5, 6, 6, 7, 8], val=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this, and I believe the first is what you're looking for...

*Solution 1.*

Call the function within the class, for which the syntax is:

```
a_solution.removeElement(...)
```

*Solution 2.*

Implement `__call__` in your class to make the instance of that class callable:

```
class Solution:
    def __call__(self, nums, val):
        lens = len(nums)
        if lens == 0:
            return 0
        x = 0
        for i in range(lens):
            if nums[i] != val:
                nums[x] = nums[i]
            x += 1
        return x
```

Comment: Credit for solution 1 goes to @Norrius. As well, as some users have stated in the comments, the problem you're trying to solve may not merit a class-based solution. (a.k.a. you're using a hammer to dig a hole in the ground)

Comment: Minor quibble: the *class* is already callable; that's why you can write `Solution(...)` instead of `Solution.__new__(...)`. Defining `__call__` make the *instances* callable. (In fact, `Solution(...)` works because `type.__call__` is defined; instances of `type` like `Solution` are thus callable.)

Answer (score 1):

To make an object "callable", one needs to define `__call__` method.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.v = a

    def __call__(self, e):
        self.v = [x for x in self.v if x != e]
        return len(self.v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.v)
```

to use the code:

```
s = Solution([1,2,3,6,6,5]) # initialize the list
s(6) # remove all '6'
s    # display s
```